# Using redux thunk and socket.io in receiving socket request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, socket.io, redux-thunk

I'm using redux thunk and socket.io, I have little clue about handling the socket io, for emit I put in action, but how about receiving? I tried
below approach in my reducer file.

```
const store =
  getUserRole() === 'member' ? import('../store') : import('../adminStore')

socket.on('receive-payment', function(payload) {
    store.dispatch({
      type: ADD_PAYMENT,
      payload
    })
})
```

I got error of `store.dispatch is not a function`. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you should probably first define these two imports in it's variables and then assign one or the other one in the store.

```
import store as store1 from '../store';
import store as store2 from '../adminStore';

const store = getUserRole() === 'member' ? store1 : store2;

socket.on('receive-payment', function(payload) {
    store.dispatch({
      type: ADD_PAYMENT,
      payload
    })
})
```

Please let me know if this helps.